# IntelliJ IDEA 14: Local history storage format

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration

I have IntelliJ IDEA 14 installed. Now I would like to read the local file history located under `$HOME/.IntelliJIdea14/system/LocalHistory` with an external program. The folder has two files: `changes.storageData` and `changes.storageRecordIndex`.

How can I open and read them to extract my file history? I already tried `unzip`, `tar -xvzf` and an SqLite browser.

**Edit:** As IntelliJ is open source, I tried taking a quick look at their source code and by searching for ".storageData", I found the [Abstract Storage](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/a5cd6ac6102731ea9b557dcc1c684340f7d8432a/platform/util/src/com/intellij/util/io/storage/A%22bstractStorage.java%20%22Abstract%20Storage) class.
Looking further there is a [LocalHistoryStorage](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/a5cd6ac6102731ea9b557dcc1c684340f7d8432a/platform/lvcs-impl/src/com/intellij/history/core/LocalHistoryStorage.java) which uses a [LocalHistoryStorageTable](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/a5cd6ac6102731ea9b557dcc1c684340f7d8432a/platform/lvcs-impl/src/com/intellij/history/core/LocalHistoryRecordsTable.java) and a [PagePool](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/a5cd6ac6102731ea9b557dcc1c684340f7d8432a/platform/util/src/com/intellij/util/io/PagePool.java).
From a quick glance it seems these storage thingies have a sort of headers in the files.
I hope that gave a good quick start.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that there is no way to read that data. It is in some proprietary format.

There is a [Jetbrains Feature Request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117052) that it should be possible to export the data.